# What should I do when my data is normal, but not homogen?

Tags: r, t-test, outliers, heteroscedasticity

My data is (n:43)genotypes with block as replication (n:2). the design is randomized complete block design. and I did normality test and the result said normal, but I did homogeneity test (levenetest) and the result is not homogen.
But I don't want to delete my outlier.

What should I do?
Do I need to do independency test?
Do I need data transformation?

Comment: Regression does not require normal data, only normal errors.  And testing data for homogeneity isn't possible, you test a model for that. Is that what you did?  Providing more details (and maybe your code) would help.